# SII webservice AEAT Producción Error facturas emitidas

Tags: c#, webservice, aeat-sii, certificado-ssl

Buenas estas semanas he estado probando el envío de facturas emitidas al entorno de pruebas de AEAT y no he tenido ningún problema. Hoy he apuntado a su entorno de producción y me dice **"No se detecta certificado digital o no se ha seleccionado correctamente"**

El codigo que empleo es con web request:

```
     var request = ( HttpWebRequest ) WebRequest.Create ( url );
            request.Headers.Add ( Consts.SOAP_ACTION );
            request.ContentType = Consts.CONTENT_TYPE;
            request.Accept = Consts.ACCEPT;
            request.Method = System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post.Method;

            //Firmamos la petición
            request.ClientCertificates.Add ( cert );



            var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes ( XML );
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

            using ( var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream () )
            {
                requestStream.Write ( bytes, 0, bytes.Length );
                requestStream.Close ();
            }

            using ( var webResponse = ( HttpWebResponse ) request.GetResponse () )
            {
                using ( var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream () )
                {
                    using ( var responseStreamReader = new StreamReader ( responseStream, true ) )
                    {
                        response = responseStreamReader.ReadToEnd ();
                        responseStreamReader.Close ();
                    }
                    responseStream.Close ();
                }
                webResponse.Close ();
            }

            return response;
```

No entiendo como es que en producción no me detecta la petición de mi certificado... ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de que está pasando?

Comment: cert  de donde sale? es nulo?

Comment: @miguel era un ejemplo, no creí que hiciera falta exponer todo el chorro ;)

Answer (score 1):

Si mal no recuerdo cada servicio tiene tres urls, uno de pruebas y dos de producción.

Uno de los dos de producción se utiliza con un certificado normal y el otro creo que necesita un certificado especial para administraciones.

```
<wsdl:service name="siiService">
        <!-- Entorno de PRODUCCION día 1 de julio 2017-->
    <wsdl:port name="SuministroFactEmitidas" binding="siiWdsl:siiBinding">
        <soap:address location="https://www1.agenciatributaria.gob.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP"/>
    </wsdl:port>
        <!-- Entorno de PRODUCCION día 1 de julio 2017 para acceso con certificado de sello -->
    <wsdl:port name="SuministroFactEmitidasSello" binding="siiWdsl:siiBinding">
        <soap:address location="https://www10.agenciatributaria.gob.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP"/>
    </wsdl:port>
        <!-- Entorno de PRUEBAS (tambien valido para acceso con certificado de sello)-->
    <wsdl:port name="SuministroFactEmitidasPruebas" binding="siiWdsl:siiBinding">
        <soap:address location="https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Comprueba si estás usando el primero en lugar del segundo. O quizás tu tipo de certificado sea el segundo.

El de pruebas admite ambos certificados.

Comment: Nos fijamos que teníamos puesta mal la url, estábamos apuntando a la del sello. Una pregunta, ¿eso del sello a que se refiere?

Comment: Yo tampoco lo acabo de tener muy claro, creo que es uno especial para las administraciones públicas. [Aquí] (https://www.sede.fnmt.gob.es/certificados/administracion-publica/informacion-general/certificado-de-sello-electronico) tienes un poco de información

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba que el certificado (aún en pruebas) lo acepta la Agencia tributaria; para los registros de facturación, los servicios web asociados a los libros registro del IVA que exigen autenticación con certificado electrónico cualificado de cliente, se pueden invocar en la subsede: www10.agenciatributaria.gob.es, en el “Port Name” específico descrito en el WDSL.